# How to rig an eyelid for a (perfectly) spherical eye?

Tags: rigging, bones, shape-keys

i'm trying to find a way to build a good but simple rig for an eyelid.  It's for a robot, so the eye will be perfectly spherical.

Actually, I just have two demi-sphere rigged on an "up" and "down" bone, so I can open and close the eyelids.

But I want it to be a bit more complex; so I could animate the "open" shape of the eyelid and give him some extra emotions.

[image]

How should I handle this ?

I had some tests using a (flat) plane that would be "projected" on the sphere (shrinkwrap or cast modifier), but it's not deforming smoothly.

Or maybe I should use shape keys somehow, like in [this example](https://cgcookie.com/questions/13056-mirroring-piero-s-left-side-eyelids-shapekey-causes-problems):
[image]
But I would have rather loved to be able to control that with bones.

I would be glad to get your advices.

Some tutoriels I've seen :

- [Rigging and Animating Cartoon Eyes with Shape Keys in Blender 2.9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR1Jzu86bTg) (nice but no way to act on the "open" shape)

[image]

- [Eye Lid Mask Rig In Grease Pencil](https://vimeo.com/393762536/940573f0e9) almost what I would like in terms of rig, but it's flat - not spherical

[image]

Thank you !